# How to readonly/disable client's information after form submission if element is created?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make the client's information readonly after a form submission once it is posted on the web page, but I can't seem to figure it out as I have the element created on submit.

```
 <form onsubmit="return false"> 
       <div id="textarea-format-structure">
          <textarea id="blogVal" placeholder="Share"></textarea>
       </div>
         <button class="btnpost">Post</button>
</form>
   <div id="my-posts-blog"></div>





 function postVal() {

     var create = document.createElement("textarea");
     var blogVal = document.getElementById("blogVal").value;
     var appendVal = document.getElementById("my-posts-blog");

       create.innerHTML += blogVal;
       appendVal.prepend(create);
 }
 var postIt = document.getElementsByClassName("btnpost")[0];
     postIt.addEventListener("click", postVal, false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `onsubmit="return false"`, you aren't doing a form submission in the first place. If your goal is just to make an interactive page and don't need to send the data anywhere, a `form` isn't needed, nor is `submit`.

A simple `button` with a `click` event will do. From there, you would create a new element that is not editable by default, like a `div`, transfer the `textarea` data into it, and add the new element to the designated area.

See comments below:

```js
// Get DOM References
let input = document.getElementById("blogVal");
let outputArea = document.getElementById("my-posts-blog");
let btn = document.querySelector(".btnpost");

// Set up event handler
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  // Create new element to show the post in
  let post = document.createElement("div");
  post.textContent = input.value; // Set the content of the post
  post.classList.add("post");     // Add pre-made class for style
  outputArea.appendChild(post);   // Add post to post area
  input.value = "";               // Reset the input
});
```

```css
.post {
  background-color:rgba(255,255,0,.3);
  border:1px solid grey;
  box-shadow:1px 1px 1px #808080;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  float:left;
  margin:3px;
  padding:4px;
  overflow-y:auto;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="textarea-format-structure">
   <textarea id="blogVal" placeholder="Share"></textarea>
</div>
<button class="btnpost">Post</button>

<div id="my-posts-blog"></div>
```

Comment: It seems as when I reach the end of the border when first typing, then once posted, the input actually goes outside the border.

Comment: @Sergio That's only because I hard-coded the size of the posts at 100px x 200px. You can make the sizes anything you want and control how to handle any overflow with CSS. I will update the answer to show this, but this is unrelated to the actual question you asked.

Comment: I see, I am just not really good at this yet, but thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

you are creating the text area, for read only you should create a paragraph.
Like so
var create = document.createElement("p");

Comment: I am aware that I can use "p", but is there a way to do readonly with "textarea"?